# How can I define such lexer rules:

Tags: antlr

I have the following tokens in my DSL:

1. It starts with a lower case letter; after that, it could be any lower case letter, upper case letter or underscore.
2. It starts with an upper case letter; after that, it could be any lower case letter, upper case letter or underscore.
3. It optionally starts with '-'; after that, it could be any lower case, letter, upper case letter, '.', '_', '-', '/' or '$'.

To my understanding, I cannot have 3 separate lexer rules because there is no way we can define them without ambiguity. I need to just define one lexer rule, using #3 because it covers #1 and #2 and in the target programming to differentiate the 3 tokens.

But I hope I am wrong because defining lexer rule is so tempting.

Please advice.

Comment: What is your question? These lexer rules are different, since it either starts with lowercase, uppercase the only problem is the 3rd one, but you can use predicates to say that if it doesn't contain those special characters it should be either 1 or 2

Comment: Understand that some programming(i.e. predicate) can solve the problem, but I was thinking if pure grammar can work out. Looks like it cannot. Thanks for confirming.